# dbt_utils.surrogate_key() with all fields except two

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am currently playing with dbt and trying to build a PSA (Persistent Staging Area) and the snapshot functionality lends itself well to this in my eyes. However, I don't have timestamps in the sources, so I have to use the "check" strategy.

For "check_cols" I would like to use a hash value, so I thought of dbt_utils.surrogate_key().

But I would like to calculate the hash value over all columns except the two columns that are always the same.

So my model looks like this:

```
{% snapshot Item_hist %}
{{
    config(
      unique_key='item_id',
      strategy='check',
      check_cols=['diff_hash'],
      target_database='PSA',
      target_schema='sourceA',
      alias= 'Item',
      invalidate_hard_deletes=True
    )
}}

select {{ dbt_utils.surrogate_key(['Tenant','ItemNo']) }} as item_id,
{{ dbt_utils.surrogate_key( dbt_utils.star(from=source('sourceA', 'item'), except=["fieldA", "fieldB"]) ) }} as diff_hash,
* 
from {{ source('sourceA', 'item') }}
{% endsnapshot %}
```

Unfortunately, the dbt_utils.surrogate_key() cannot handle the return value of dbt_utils.star().
How could I proceed here so that surrogate_key() can calculate a hash value from the return?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking the source code, [dbt_utils.star](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/sql/star.sql), returns the columns in the format

```
  `col1` as `col1`,
  `col2` as `col2`,
  ...
```

The quotes depend on the adapter (BigQuery in the example) and the alias using `as` is included because the method can get `suffix` and `prefix` parameters

`dbt_utils.surrogate_key` is expecting a list of values, instead of the string returned by `dbt_utils.star`

I have found a solution in [dbt Slack group](https://www.getdbt.com/community/join-the-community) using [get_columns_in_relation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/adapter#get_columns_in_relation)

Thanks to Lee Werner who posted the solution:

```
{%- set columns = get_columns_in_relation(ref('my_model')) -%}

{% set column_names = columns|map(attribute='name')|list %}

SELECT
{{ dbt_utils.surrogate_key( column_names )}} as HashID,
*
FROM {{ref('my_model')}}
```

In your case, you want to ignore some columns, so we can apply a [reject](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.reject) filter to the list

```
{% snapshot Item_hist %}
{{
    config(
      unique_key='item_id',
      strategy='check',
      check_cols=['diff_hash'],
      target_database='PSA',
      target_schema='sourceA',
      alias= 'Item',
      invalidate_hard_deletes=True
    )
}}

{% set columns = get_columns_in_relation(source('sourceA', 'item')) -%}
{% set column_names = columns|map(attribute='name')|reject("in", ['fieldA','fieldB'])|list %}

select {{ dbt_utils.surrogate_key(['Tenant','ItemNo']) }} as item_id,
{{ dbt_utils.surrogate_key(column_names) }} as diff_hash,
* 
from {{ source('sourceA', 'item') }}
{% endsnapshot %}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out for this one. That seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but you should use `dbt_utils.get_filtered_columns_in_relation` instead since it output list instead of string like `dbt_utils.star`.

Example:

```
with src as (
    select 
        *,
        {{ 
            dbt_utils.generate_surrogate_key(
                dbt_utils.get_filtered_columns_in_relation(
                    from=ref('stg__test_scd'),
                    except=['load_time']
                )
            )
        }} as _scd_record_id
    from {{ ref('stg__test_scd') }}
)

select * from src
```